# how to isolate Maxim dallas one wire interface

Tags: digital-isolator

I would like to isolate my thermocouple amplifier using a adum1200.
Given the following illustration of the chip, does this chip allow me bidirectional comms on the same pin?

[image]

I hooked up power on vdd1 and gnd1 to 5v rail on my uno.

then provided another sperate 5v (plug pack and 7805) to vdd2 and gnd2.

ViA ----> to my digital pin 2 then voA to my one wire amplifier.

The code says it can't find the amplified but it works pefectly fine when I don't use the amplifier.

I'm guessing I need a chip that has an open drain output

I fell into the trap of believing the banner specs on the datasheet if that's the case.

out of interest how are they claiming it's bi directional then. iS it because the adum1201 has 1/1 directionality

Comment: I'd guess you need the  adum1201  ...http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM1200_1201.pdf but even then more digging is needed

Comment: ... and that chip does not offer bidirectional coms if the figure is correct-- either on the same pin or using different pins.  Both channels go in the same direction.

Comment: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5134

Comment: TBH i ASSUMED (like an idiot) the square s symbol means it's bidirectional. I now know it stands for schmitt trigger.  WHEN I FLAMING LEARN

Answer (score 1):

Use directions in Dallas chip directly and properly, instead of isolation and get that working first.  Then show waveforms if flawed.

> STRONG PULLUP
>   To provide energy for a temperature conversion or for copying data from the scratchpad to the EEPROM,a low-impedance pullup of the 1-Wire bus to 5V is required just after the corresponding command has been sent by the master. During temperature conversion or copying the scratchpad, the bus master controls the transition from a state where the data line is idling high via the pullup resistor to a state where the data line is actively driven to 5V, providing a minimum of 1mA of current for each DS1920 doing temperature conversion. This low impedance pullup should be active for 0.75 seconds for temperature conversion or at least 10ms for copying to the scratchpad. After that, the data line returns to an idle high state controlled by the pullup resistor.

read the following

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/148

in particular ...  impedance matching and active pullup

Consider for EMI reduction, and use twisted pair with CM choke for improved noise rejection.

If you need isolation for hiV  or CM rejection give reasons and consider above instead.

## update

Assuming your previous thermal questions are related, do you have the negative side of the Thermocouple wire grounded to aluminum block? **The tip must be electrically insulated yet thermally coupled, perhaps with oil or thermal grease.**

[image]

extra info

---

Thermal oils are available in a wide range of specifications. Different manufacturers produce different oils under different brand names. Different specifications suit various needs of the process and applications. Some of the commonly used brands are

- Therminol from Solutia Inc.
- Dowtherm from Dow Chemical Co.
- Exceltherm from Radco Industries Inc.
- Paratherm from Paratherm Corp.

The most important characteristic is the maximum temperature of service. The oil is thermally stable till this temperature. It should be borne in mind that the cost increases exponentially with increase in the maximum temperature limit. Currently the thermal oils are available up to 400 °C.

Comment: hi tony can you explain what you mean by directions? the dallas temperature library am using doesn't mention this. It does work without the isolator.  The reason I need isolation is to have a floating front end for my thermocouple as suggested by another EE on this site.

Comment: Sorry Temp only is unidirectional, but commands require bi-directional communication. I think a balun or CM choke is better. It gives low differential impedance and high CM impedance over the frequency of interest, which is low here so large CM choke is needed, larger than ethernet PHY balun

Comment: Sorry tony so you;re saying you think I should just add a common mode choke and forget about the digital isolator? if so can you advise I'm just a average hobbiest wanting a working 3d printer.

Comment: something of this size you mean http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/leaded-inductors/7926173/

Comment: no this is around same inductance but higher current. First scope your signals in lab to simulate environment then see what problems exist (vs datasheet) and implement active pullup then twisted pair for sensor and ferrite sleeve over printer motor wire pairs if not already, then last resort CM choke for sensor.

Comment: see up dated answer and show scope results.

Comment: ah THANKS A MILLION. If someone else said this to me I wouldn't be BASHING MY HEAD AGAINST THE WALL. U have no idea how much i've been struggling with such a simple thing  NOBODY SUGGESTED THIS. If only everyone was as helpful to beginners as yourself.

Comment: ok most welcome, report back with waveforms or data .... along with coffee and pastry ;)

Comment: The whole point of me using a thermocuple was because I was told in order to print in PET the hotend needs to be over 300 degrees celcius.  Can you recommend a themal grease since the ones from farnell/rs seem to be only 200C

Comment: I tried some silcone heatsink compound but despite applyiing genorous amount to the thermcouple, i measure continuity from the hotend(aluminium block) to thermocouple

Comment: Of course it's a bimetallic joint. This issue is not to disturb the tip and float your supplies and only ground to machine to get less disturbance RF Cap to earth ground elsewhere if necessary as in internal AC line filter is ok.